# When did Star Trek first start using low lights as a norm for red alert conditions?

Tags: star-trek

In older shows such as *Star Trek: The Next Generation* and *Star Trek: Voyager*, corridors were *not* dimmed during red alert.

But in the newer shows, the lights are usually dimmed.

In what show did this first happen?

Comment: It's worth noting this happens on real world navy ships.  When performing night operations, having a brightly lit bridge makes it difficult to see out the windows, as you'd just be seeing your own reflection all the time, so they will dim the lights, and often they are red because that's least likely to affect your night vision.  Of course, Star Trek ships don't have windows on the bridge, it's just a viewscreen, but given most of what's shown on the screen is the blackness of space, it makes sense to dim the lights in order to see it better, just like you dim the lights in a movie theater.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman yeah, but the lights are dimmed all the time for night running, not just during a red alert.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I'll also note that while some ships do use viewscreens, other ships (particularly those shown in the newer shows) use actual glass windows.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry i think you mean actual *transparent aluminum* windows :)

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe +1. My bad...thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the first (in production order) instance was in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*.

[image: Still from TMP showing dimmed red lighting on the bridge]

You can see the bridge lighting is dimmed, but not the corridor/turbolift for some reason.

This design continues through the original cast films, even while *Star Trek: The Next Generation* avoids it.

Comment: They keep the exits well lit in case you need to abandon the bridge in an emergency, like the room is filled with smoke from all the exploding computer consoles or something.

Comment: You'd think they'd keep everything well-lit (like in the earlier TV shows) so you can see what you're doing at your action station.

Comment: That's why they go with dim, red light, rather than NO light.  Also the controls are backlit, so you can see most of what counts.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman but just keeping everything lit as normal would be better

Comment: @OrangeDog, low lights also makes you focus on your work instead of being distracted with what the others are doing.

Comment: @OrangeDog The early shows were actually *over*-lit, due to issues with the cameras.  This is, for example, why the Enterprise-D is less brightly lit in *Generations*, when they were using better-quality (and more expensive) **movie** cameras, rather than **TV** cameras.  This let them light the sets as originally intended, rather than the extra-bright workaround they would up with.

Comment: TNG *did* use low lights for [blue alerts](https://youtu.be/K5WJ7tiem3A?t=49).

Comment: @Chronocidal What makes you say "as originally intended"? It isn't as though the TOS or TNG set designers were surprised by the limits of TV cameras, they were experienced TV set designers who would know how to play to the strengths and weaknesses of the format.